# Firebase Database Send information just for validation and not for saving in the database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I wanted to know if it is possible to send data to firebase database that is to be used for only validation and not to be saved. 
For example if I send {"myauth" : "abc123"} the validation rule will only check if the newdata.child("myauth").equals("abc123") and is not saved to the database. Like

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".validate": "newData.child('myauth').val() === 'abc123'",
     ".read": true,
    ".write": true      
  }
}
```

So whenever I send a data to that node, that is to be written, the validation will check for child myauth and if the value equals "abc123" only then go forward with the write operation, but not save the myauth variable to the database. I understand that saving the data to the database is a easy workaround, but is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trigger the `.write` rules without an actual write operation. But if you just declare one child node as your "validation tester" and only write there.

Comment: That is use a myauth value with every write request as a place holder? Will that be an overkill looking from a scale-able solution? I am working on android.

Comment: The security rules are only run on the server. So you'll need to send the data no matter what. Whether it actually tries to write them to the database or not is fairly small compared to that. For best user experience: first try to prevent invalid input (e.g. use dropdowns instead of text fields), then validate the input *before* sending it to the server, and only then rely on the server-side rules to catch mistakes and rogue users. The security rules are there to ensure data integrity/authorized access, not to ensure a good user experience.